# How to Access a Value from a complex multi-relationship SOQL query?

Tags: apex, soql

I have this monster of a query:

```
List<Case> updatedCases = [SELECT Id,ProductId, Vehicle__c, 
                               (SELECT Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r ORDER BY 
                                Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1) FROM Case WHERE Id 
                             IN :cases AND (Type = 'Repair' OR Type = 'Routine Maintenance') AND 
                              Status = 'Closed'];
```

And I need to assign the value of the Maintenance_Cycle__c to a new case (in the Date_Due__c field) like so (except this one doesn't work):

```
 List<Case> newCases = new List<Case>();
    for(Case a:updatedCases){
        Case b = new Case();
        b.Type = 'Routine Maintenance';
        b.Vehicle__c = a.Vehicle__c;
        b.Subject = 'Routine Maintenance Request';
        b.Date_Reported__c = Date.today();
        b.Date_Due__c = Date.today() + updatedCases.get(Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c);
        newCases.add(b);
    }
    insert newCases;
```

How would I retrieve that value from my SOQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value from `a`:

```
if(a.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r.size() == 1) {
  a.Due_Date__c = Date.today() + a.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r[0].Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to research some more to get the following code that executes without any error: 

 `if(a.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r.size() == 1) {`
                Decimal numV = a.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r[0].Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c;
                Integer cycle = numV.intValue();
                b.Date_Due__c = b.Date_Reported__c.addDays(cycle);
   }  
`